# How to access the array that is value of a QVariantMap?

Tags: qvariant

I have a QVariantMap whose key is a string and value is an array(of ints or strings)

How do I get the individual elements of the array?

map["key"] has a method toList(). Can I apply that to arrays?

Answer (score 5):

Yes,

```
QString first_string_of_key = QVariantMap["key"].toList()[0];
```

but this is only for reading. Any attempt to write will not work because QVariant will return a copy of the list. Read this post: [Assigning to nested QVariantMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11090846/assigning-to-nested-qvariantmap)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this if we say that we have an iterator `it` moving around the keys:

we could say

```
if(it.value("key").type()==QMetaType::ByteArray)
  std::vector<std::string> vs_array_valus(QVariantMap["key"].value().toArray());
```

Or direct use as below:

```
if(QVariantMap["key"].value().type()==QMetaType::ByteArray)
std::vector<std::string> vs_array_valus(QVariantMap["key"].value().toArray());
```

Hope this Will help.